# Using turbo trainer with solid axles

Tags: quick-release, turbo-trainer

I just bought the In'ride 100 without checking if it fits my bicycle. My Triban 100 bicycle has solid axles and plain axle nuts.  Now  I want to know if it's possible to attach a quick release to a Triban 100 and steps to do it if possible.

Also is it possible to attach the rear wheel to the trainer without the quick release,  I have already tried with the rear wheel as it is now... And it doesn't sit on the trainer well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing rear wheel skewer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/66952/replacing-rear-wheel-skewer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Installing quick release axles requires completely replacing the axle. It's possible but does require a few extra tools and parts to disassemble the rear hub. If you install a QR, don't forget to choose a trainer specific QR, they are strong and have tough metal nuts.

The simplest method though would be some other type of axle nut which is compatible with the turbo. Internet search for 'turbo trainer axle nuts' seems to be a good start. They have rounded metal ends and look like this:

[image: Turbo compatible axle nuts]